# Not showing second TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

Quick question. I have a layout with two tables. One table is a header and the second is the table itself.
I separated them in two voids and separately they work as expected but if I try both of them only the header is shown.

Did I miss something?

**Update 1**

void addTable(); works because when it opens it shows numeric keyboard. So adding the view is not working

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TableLayout>


    <ScrollView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/table2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"></TableLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

```html
public class SingleGate extends AppCompatActivity {

    CheckBox checkBox, checkBox1;
    TextView tv, tv1, qty, qty1, txt1, txt2, txt3;
    Button addBtn, minusBtn;
    EditText input;
    TableLayout tableLayout;
    Integer column1, column2, column3;
    TableLayout table, table2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.single_gate);

        Toast.makeText(this, "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table1);
        table2 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table2);

        addHeader();
        addTable();

    }

    public void addHeader() {


        TableLayout.LayoutParams lp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        table.setLayoutParams(lp);
        table.setStretchAllColumns(true);

        TableLayout.LayoutParams rowLp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TableRow.LayoutParams cellLp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.6f);

        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

        TextView hdr1 = new TextView(this);
        TextView hdr2 = new TextView(this);
        TextView hdr3 = new TextView(this);
        TextView hdr4 = new TextView(this);

        //ADD FIRST CELL
        hdr1.setText("A");
        hdr1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        hdr1.setMinimumHeight(100);
        hdr1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cell_shape));
        row.addView(hdr1, cellLp);
        //ADD SECOND CELL
        hdr2.setText("NR");
        hdr2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        hdr2.setMinimumHeight(100);
        hdr2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cell_shape));
        row.addView(hdr2, cellLp);
        //ADD THIRD CELL
        hdr3.setText("B");
        hdr3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        hdr3.setMinimumHeight(100);
        hdr3.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cell_shape));
        row.addView(hdr3, cellLp);
        //ADD FOURTH CELL
        hdr4.setText("NR");
        hdr4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        hdr4.setMinimumHeight(100);
        hdr4.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cell_shape));
        row.addView(hdr4, cellLp);
        table.addView(row, rowLp);

    }

    public void addTable() {
//        TableLayout table2 = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table2);
// Java. You succeed!
        TableLayout.LayoutParams lp2 = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        table2.setLayoutParams(lp2);
        table2.setStretchAllColumns(true);

        TableLayout.LayoutParams rowLp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        TableRow.LayoutParams cellLp2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        for (int r = 1; r < 12; ++r) {
            TableRow row2 = new TableRow(this);

            TextView tbl1 = new TextView(this);
            EditText tbl2 = new EditText(this);
            TextView tbl3 = new TextView(this);
            EditText tbl4 = new EditText(this);

//            This is very useful if someone already made some InputFilter. It overrides android:maxlength
// in xml file, so we need to add LengthFilter this way.

            InputFilter[] filterArray = new InputFilter[1];
            filterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(2);

            //ADD FIRST CELL
            tbl1.setText("A" + r);
            tbl1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbl1.setMinimumHeight(100);
            tbl1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cell_shape));
            row2.addView(tbl1, cellLp2);
            //ADD SECOND CELL
            tbl2.setHint("0");
            tbl2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbl2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            tbl2.setFilters(filterArray);
            tbl2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.table_cell));
            row2.addView(tbl2, cellLp2);
            //ADD THIRD CELL
            tbl3.setText("B" + r);
            tbl3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbl3.setMinimumHeight(100);
            tbl3.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cell_shape));
            row2.addView(tbl3, cellLp2);
            //ADD FOURTH CELL
            tbl4.setHint("0");
            tbl4.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbl4.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            tbl4.setFilters(filterArray);
            tbl4.setMinimumHeight(100);
            tbl4.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.table_cell));
            row2.addView(tbl4, cellLp2);
            table2.addView(row2, rowLp);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

Screenshot added

[image]

Comment: have you tried to set fixed height for first `TableLayout` (e.g. 200dp)? also then you may change `android:layout_height="0dp"` and set `android:layout_weight="1"` for second one

Comment: Thx for quick reply. It does not do difference.